# Save Opened Text File to Original Location

Tags: c#, datagridview, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I am creating an application that will allow me to open a .txt file and edit the values (weight=60, height =50, etc) in a DataGridView.  My issue is that I am able to upload the .txt file using OpenFileDialog but am unable to write over and save it in it's previous location.

For clarification, here is my method to upload text files:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream;
        openFileDialog1.FileName = string.Empty;
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var compareType = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
            var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            if (extension.Equals(".txt", compareType))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())
                    {              
                        string file = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                        string line;

                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            string[] words = line.Split('=');
                            paramList.Add(new Parameter(words[0], words[1]));
                        }
                        BindGrid();
                    }
                }
```

And what I've tried to save the file:

```
public void WriteToTextFile(DataGridView dgvParam)
    {
        String file_name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(openFileDialog1.FileName))
        {
            for (Int32 row = 0; row < dgvParam.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (Int32 col = 0; col < dgvParam.Rows[row].Cells.Count; col++)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString()))
                        sb.Append("=");  //any delimiter you choose
                    sb.Append(dgvParam.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString().ToUpper());
                }
                objWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            }
        }
```

It says it is openFileDialog is currently in use and it cannot reach it!  Any suggestions or recommendations would be really appreciated!

Comment: You have a hole bunch of variables that have no reason to exist.

Comment: In the `WriteToTextFile()` function, where does `openFileDialog1` come from?  Is it a global variable?  Is this all of the relevant code?

Comment: @JayBuckman Yes, I tried to make it a global variable (I know, not a good move) just to test and see if I could make it a static path and reference it later.  Unfortunately, this didn't work.  The only code I didn't include was the BindGrid method which just sets my paramList as my datasource.

Comment: You've got some duplication in the code.  `using (myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())`  actually reads the file contents into `myStream` but you never use it.  Instead you open a new reader with `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);`.  But you never dispose the reader which leaves the file open as @slaks mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dispose your `reader` variable.

You should get rid of the first `using` statement entirely and wrap that in a `using` statement instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  So what you're saying is just assign the myStream variable/get rid of the using statement.  Then instead of a while loop, have
using(line = reader.ReadLine()){method} ?  That didn't seem to work for me

Comment: @Tarheel81: Learn what the `using` statement actually means.  You need to wrap your disposable stream reader in a `using` statment.